# APIs/SDKs for 2.1 and 2.2 won't install - thinks Windows 7 is Linux?

Tags: android

Trying to install either SDKs for 2.1 or 2.2 in Eclipse, I get the same err msg:

Android SDK Manager Log:
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-2.2_r03-linux.zip (Access is denied)

My OS is 64-bit Windows 7.

So why it's even looking for linux file, I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the SDK Manager for Android independently from start menu - but run it "As Administrator" (mouse right-click on SDK Manager to have the selection to run "As Administrator").
This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the installer as administrator?  Same problem was reported [here](http://pastorcmentarny.blogspot.com/2011/08/solving-problem-with-access-is-denied.html)

Comment: I was able to install 2.3.3, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, and 4.0 just fine, so I wouldn't think that would be the issue...

Comment: He gives some advice, but now how to do it:"You need run AndroidSDK application as administrator, to do that you need 'run as administrator' button from the context menu. (btw. You may be user who has administrator account but that doesn't mean that your run specific program as administrator!) "  - I get no context menu in the SDK...???

Comment: I had the problem while running SDKManager from Eclipse. When I ran it from Explorer, I was able to use the "Run as Administrator" from the context menu, and now 2.1 and 2.2 are installed.

Interestingly, I did get a msg from SDKManager that java was not found where it was expected, and so that I should add its actual path to the env. variables' PATH

Answer (score 0):

rekindled the android instalation of Help -> Install New Software of its move quickly because it is already instaled and as I click SDK Manager I found all verions

Comment: This sentence is hard to understand, and as far as I can see does not answer the question